# Efficient way to match postgis linestrings against a GPS log

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am working on a website that allows users to upload a GPX file and the website has a table full of linestrings stored in postgis. These linestrings are sections of road and trails. Then the website works out from the gpx file all the linestrings that that the gps log traveled along (the direction is important). The problem is there could be millions of these linestrings in the database and working out if the gps log traveled along one is fairly expensive so I need some way of determining the linestrings that are likely to be matches before pulling them out of the database.

One idea I had was to store the first point of the linestring in it's own indexed column. Then draw a box that contains the whole gpx log and look up every linestring with a starting point in that box. This would allow for somewhat fast searches I think but if the gpx log is long and moves diagonally it could create a huge box where most of the area is very far away from any of the gpx trackpoints.

A refinement of this idea was to draw multiple smaller boxes that contain the gps trace. This covers much less empty space but requires more queries.

[image]
The green line is an example gps trace and the red and blue lines are the example boxes for queries.

What methods could I use to quickly find the linestrings in postgis that are likely to be a match with the gps trace?

Comment: In case I got your question right: Have you considered spliting the linestring into points and then extracting from your large table onle the geometries that are *near* these points?

Comment: To clarify, the table holds all the linestrings and there is one gpx log. I have considered doing searches by linestrings starting next to one of the gpx log points but a gpx file could have thousands of points and I don't know if you can do one query to find everything near a list of the points.

Comment: I added a comment as an answer... it'd be too large here. Let me know when you're done, so that I either improve or delete it :-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an efficient way
First : create spatial indexes if you don't have them

```
create index on gpstrace gist(geom);
create index on boxes gist(geom);
```

Now if you want all gpstraces that are partially in your box then

```
select *
  from gpstrace g
 where exists (select from boxes b where st_dwithin(g.geom, b.geom,0) and b.id=1);
```

If you want only gpstraces that are completly wihtin your box then

```
select *
  from gpstrace g
 where exists (select from boxes b where st_within(g.geom, b.geom) and b.id=1);
```